# Как выключить аппаратную виртуализацию на мак для Virtual Box?

Tags: virtualbox, mac

У меня не получается запустить виртуальную машину windows на мак, появляется ошибка "Функция аппаратной виртуализации включена для данной машины, но не поддерживается вашим хостом". Как выключить виртуализацию?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой у вас мак?

Comment: MacBook Air (m1, 2020) Big Sur

Comment: Без аппаратной виртуализации виртуалбокс не поддерживает эмуляцию x86-64 (только 32-битный x86), и программная эмуляция будет всё равно очень медленная и грустная, так что рекомендую вам переосмыслить свою цель

Comment: как мне исправить проблему? аппаратная виртуализация не поддерживается хостом (работоспособность не так важна, главное чтобы проблема была решена)

Comment: В интернете пишут, что VirtualBox в принципе невозможно запустить на M1

Comment: Конкретно "отключить аппаратную виртуализацию" можно [специальной командой в консоли](https://superuser.com/a/1672737), но подозреваю, что это вам мало поможет